# Snap to angle if number is within a threshold

Tags: c#, math

I am wondering what is a simple way to check if an angle is within a certain thershold to a specific angle.

Say 45 degrees, i currently can get the exact multiple of 45 degrees, but i would like a margin of 10 degrees either side to also be valid for the whole 360 degree circle. But not sure of a clean way to do it.

This is what i have currently:

```
float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(currentGrid.Vector3,Vector3.right, Vector3.up); //[-180,180]
angle += 360;
angle %= 360; //[0,360]
int angle2 = (int)(Mathf.RoundToInt(angle / 5f) * 5f); //snap to nearest 5 degrees

if (angle2 % 45 == 0 || /*angle is within threshold of a multiple of 45 degrees*/ ){
   print("Hello");
}
```

Is there a way to do this without lots of if checks for every 45 degree angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the same way that you used for the 5°:

```
var closest45 = (int)(Mathf.RoundToInt(angle2 / 45f) * 45f);
if(Math.Abs(closest45 - angle2) < 10) //allow a 10° tolerance to either side
    angle2 = closest45;
```

Comment: Hmm that seems to only work on one side of the vector for some reason, see here: 

https://imgur.com/7ONE77A  its green when its close enough, yet on the other side of the line its always red now matter how close you get.

Comment: Have you looked at the numbers in your code? The `Math.Abs()` should make it work for both sides.

Comment: Ah yeah i made a mistake in my code. Thanks. Works now :)